# Svelte store not triggered when value chages, only when $: is prefixed

Tags: store, reactive, svelte

As I understand, when using Svelte store with $ prefixed it's automatically subscribed to value changes.

Having the following code, whenever users.name store value is changed it should trigger one of the two statements.

```
 <script>
    if (!$userS.name) {
        list = Promise.reject({message:'You are not allowed to view this section!'});
    } else {
        list = getList('api/carousel/' + escape(term));
    }
 </script>
```

But the only way the previous code is working is when the if statement it's prefixed by "**$:**".

`$: if (!$userS.name) { ...`

So why is need the extra reactive dollar sign if it's already subscribed to store value changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component init script, that is the code inside the`<script>` tag, is **not** reactive. It runs once when your component is created and that's all. Think class constructor.

Only the code in reactive blocks `$:` is kept in sync and reruns when (reactive) variables they contain change.

The `$` prefix gives you the *value* inside the store. In your example, the `user` variable is the store itself. `console.log` it, you'll see it is an object with a `subscribe` method etc. The prefixed variable gives you the value inside the store. Behind the scene, Svelte makes a subscription to the store (i.e. calls its `subscribe` method) when your component is created, and unsubscribes when it is destroyed.

Meanwhile, if the value changes, the `$` prefixed variable will be reactive. But it will only have an effect if it sits in a reactive context. That is, either a reactive expression/statement `$:`, or in the markup. This is true for any reactive source (props, top level variables...).